# django on update modelform not presenting stored value as selected

Tags: django, django-forms

I have an uninteresting modelform.  One of the model fields, occupation, is a foreignkey to a table containing a long, long list of options.  The problem is for update, the rendered form, which is rendered via crispy, does not set focus to the stored value (mark it as the selected option in the `<select><option...>` code).  Instead, it shows the empty choice.  I see the initial value does point to the id of the database's record.

To make this a little more "interesting," I want to change `occupation.to_field_name` to `occupation.code` (a charfield).  I've been futzing with the form's `init` as given below.  I can convert the option values to the form I want, but I cannot get the form to present the stored value as selected (and present as the field's selected value).

How do I do this?  Do I have to do it via JS or am I doing something wrong with the form?  Thanks.

```
    
    class Meta:
        model = TutorOptionalServiceAndDemographics
        fields = ['highest_degree',
                  'country_of_birth',
                  'immigrant',
                  'us_citizen',
                  'employment_status_at_enrollment',
                  'occupation',
                  'employer_name',
                  'referral',
                  ]

        labels = {
            'highest_degree': 'Highest degree/diploma earned',
            'us_citizen': 'US Citizen:',
            'immigrant': 'Immigrant:',
            'country_of_birth': 'Country of Birth:',
            'employment_status_at_enrollment': 'Employment status at time of registration:',
            'occupation': 'Occupation:',
            'employer_name': 'Employer Name:',
            'referral': 'Referred by or heard about the program from source:',
        }

        help_texts = {
            'employment_status_at_enrollment': '',
            'referral': 'Select all that apply',
        }

        yes_no = [('True', 'Yes'), ('False', 'No')]
        widgets = {
            'immigrant': HorizontalRadioSelect(choices=yes_no),
            'us_citizen': HorizontalRadioSelect(choices=yes_no),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TutorOptionalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # futzing goes here

        self.helper = FormHelper(self)
        self.helper.attrs['autocomplete'] = 'off'
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-gather-name'
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        # self.helper.form_action = ''
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-5'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-6'
        self.helper.form_tag = False

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'highest_degree',
            'country_of_birth',
            InlineRadios('immigrant'),
            InlineRadios('us_citizen'),
            'employment_status_at_enrollment',
            'occupation',
            'employer_name',
            'referral',
        )
```

```
        # for i in self.fields['occupation']._queryset:
        #     print(f"i is {i} {i.id}")
        initial_value = [x for x in self.fields['occupation']._queryset if x.id ==  self.initial['occupation']]
        print(f"initial value is {initial_value[0].code}")
        self.fields['occupation'].initial = initial_value[0].code
        self.fields['occupation'].to_field_name = 'code'
        pprint(vars(self.fields['occupation']))
        # print("widget")
        # pprint(vars(self.fields['occupation'].widget))
        # try:
        #     actual_occupation = Occupation.objects.get(id=29)
        # this is a hardcoded example just trying to figure out what's happening
        #     self.fields['occupation'].initial = actual_occupation.code
        # except Occupation.DoesNotExist:
        #     self.fields['occupation'].initial = ""
        # print(f"after ")
        # pprint(vars(self.fields['occupation']))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a hack way around this by adding a js function on document.ready and passing the answer in the context.  It's a simple loop through the select options and then adding a selected property to the right option.

I'd still like to know how to have done this properly using just django objects.  It seems I'm doing something wrong or not initializing the widget or the field on the form correctly.